# Is there any commonality between the use of Parseval's Identity in two different contexts?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

In Fourier analysis, [Parseval's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) relates to "the summability of the Fourier series as a function."

In inner product space analysis, the "identity" works as a "Pythagorean theorem" relating the squared length of a vector to the sums of squares of its components.

How would the same theorem be central to two different applications? Or are they more or less connected because the "summability" of the Fourier Series, is somehow also based on a "Pythagorean" theorem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the first statement is supposed to mean. Would you clarify a bit?

Comment: The Lebesgue space $L^2$ is, in some ways, the natural place to do Fourier analysis (at least at the beginning). It's also an inner product space.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: that's from the link. It goes on to say that Parseval's identity is a "Pythagorean theorem" for inner product spaces. So the question is, there are Fourier series and there are inner product spaces, and somehow, Parseval's identity connects the two. But maybe the thing that is confusing me is how a Fourier series is an "inner product space?"

Comment: Fourier series and inner product spaces are not connected like that. The thing is that Fourier series (often) are considered in the context of a background inner product space (usually $L^2([a,b])$). The connection is via Parseval's theorem; it basically says that the Fourier series converges to the function in the $L^2$ norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier theorem is in a way a special case of Parseval's identity. Consider the following: If you look at the space $L^2$ with inner product

$$\left\langle f,g \right\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\overline{g(x)} dx$$

Then the functions $e^{ikx}, k\in\mathbb{Z}$ form an orthonormal basis, so Parseval tells you 
$$\|f\|^2 = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \left|\left\langle f,e^{ikx}\right\rangle\right|^2 $$

However $c_k = \left\langle f,e^{ikx}\right\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)e^{-ikx} dx$ is exactly the $k$-th Fourier coefficient, so this is nothing other than Parseval's identity for Fourier series.

It all comes down to the fact, that taking the Fourier series of a function is nothing other then expressing this function in the basis given by $e^{ikx}$:
$$ f = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}  \left\langle f,e^{ikx}\right\rangle e^{ikx} = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} c_k e^{ikx} $$

(Your constants may vary depending on definitions)

Answer (score -2):

NO, summability in Pythagorean has nothing to do with with Parseval's theorem.

It just says that energy of the "system" is always same no matter how you look at it! So you calculate the energy in time domain, OR, you transform your function to another domain (e.g. frequency), the energy remains the same.

One way to look at it is that the preservation of basic physical law. For instance, if you want to calculate the kinetic energy of a system: $\frac{1}{2}m||v||^2$. Now you calculate the velocity in Cartesian coordinate/polar coordinate/cylindrical coordinate, the energy would remain the same, now matter how you look at the system. The same logic applies here!

No matter how one mess around a system, the basic physical laws always conserves itself. It's just a matter of perspective.

Comment: This is a nice physical interpretation however I have to disagree with you in a point, the Pythagorean theorem is exactly Parseval's theorem (the inner product space version) applied to $\mathbb{R}^n$. They may not have a physical connection but mathematicaly they are really closely related.

Comment: This answer can't be any more wrong.

Comment: These theorems have little to do with energy or conservation. They are about distance and projectability.